# how to change the localhost to machine name?

Tags: mysql, connection, webserver, localhost, mantis

I am running a webserver for Mantis BT. I have configured it on my laptop for test phase. The user's which I have created manually receive a URL for initial sign-up. they can only connect to me by replacing the localhost in the URL with my laptop name. is there any way to replace the localhost with my machine name in MySQL?

Comment: You should not need to, as the website code in on your PC and the MySQL Server is also on your PC, therefore the website database access code will still see the MySQL Server on localhost

Comment: That is unless you are trying to connect to the database directly from a remote client. Then all they should need is yor ip address and a user account that is setup to allow access from a remote ip.

Comment: There will be instances where I would be using Wifi or ethernet connection so the IP address would be different. So I thought of configuring localhost to my machine name. I just don't know where should I make the changes.

Comment: Then you need a dynamic dns address. See dyndns.com or noip.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set g_path in config_inc.php. For example:

```
$g_path = "http://my-hostname/demo/mantis";
```

Comment: my hostname is "localhost". should I put my computer name in place of hostname in the $g_path ?

Comment: if you put localhost, then you may not be able to access Mantis from any other computer. You probably need to have a unique name for your computer and corresponding entries in a local DNS